# insert checkbox selected value into database on submit in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple checkboxes and input fields (the value of input fields is coming from a database table `leader_info`). I am selecting some checkboxes and I want when I click on submit button value of those fields is inserted into database table (`tbl_team`).

Here is my code:

```
<td >
    <input type="hidden" id="chkids" name="chkid[0]">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ChkIds" value="<?php echo $row['leader_id']; ?>" name="selected[]">
</td>
<td><span><?php echo $i++; ?></span></td>
<td><span><?php echo $row['leader_name']; ?></span></td>
<td><?php echo $row['facebook']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['twitter']; ?></td>
<td ><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>

<?php
$test=$_POST['selected'];
foreach ($test as $item)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO add_team (leader_name,flike,tlike,value) VALUES ('$item')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

but only pick one value , i want to insert all values in corresponding columns.

Comment: You want to do an ajax call to save them? Is it a normal form? Show us what you have done at now with the action page

Comment: It is sensible to cut out parts of the code that have nothing to do with your question, e.g. all those `bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center"`s .

Comment: you not even have an sql statement somewhere. please check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp to at least try to write an sql statement on your own.

Comment: You have not posted any attempt at Updating the database! Show some effort and we may be more inclined to help you ;-)